# Guzzle: Magic request methods require a URI and optional options array

Tags: php, symfony, sharepoint, guzzle

I'm using https://github.com/golincode/sharepoint-oauth-app-client which is outdated and uses Guzzle version 5. My Symfony application uses Guzzle 6. I'm trying to update the outdated code to work with Guzzle 6 but I encounter the following error:

```
Magic request methods require a URI and optional options array
```

The code in the controller.

```
$settings = [
            'site' => [
                'resource'  => '00000000-0000-ffff-0000-000000000000/example.sharepoint.com@09g7c3b0-f0d4-416d-39a7-09671ab91f64',
                'client_id' => '52848cad-bc13-4d69-a371-30deff17bb4d/example.com@09g7c3b0-f0d4-416d-39a7-09671ab91f64',
                'secret'    => 'YzcZQ7N4lTeK5COin/nmNRG5kkL35gAW1scrum5mXVgE=',
            ]
        ];
        // create a SharePoint Site instance
        $site = SPSite::create('https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/', $settings);
```

SPSite.php Create function

```
public static function create($url, array $settings = [])
{
    // ensure we have a trailing slash
    if (is_string($url)) {
        $url = sprintf('%s/', rtrim($url, '/'));
    }

    $settings = array_replace_recursive($settings, [
        'site' => [], // SharePoint Site configuration
        'http' => [   // Guzzle HTTP Client configuration
            'base_url' => $url,
        ],
    ]);

    $http = new Client($settings['http']);

    return new static($http, $settings['site']);
}
```

Client.php call function

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if (count($args) < 1) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Magic request methods require a URI and optional options array');
    }

    $uri = $args[0];
    $opts = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : [];

    return substr($method, -5) === 'Async'
        ? $this->requestAsync(substr($method, 0, -5), $uri, $opts)
        : $this->request($method, $uri, $opts);
}
```

I don't know what is changed between version 5 and 6 that makes this code not work anymore. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Are you sure the change is caused by Guzzle? The if condition in the beginning of your `__call()` method in `Client.php` checks for `count($args) < 1` and in `SPSite.php` you overwrite `$settings['site']` with an empty array and then `return new static($http, $settings['site']);` I am guessing that the empty array `$settings['site']` is the cause of your problem. In any case it looks like your changes when upgrading the code introduced the bug. You might want to use XDebug or `var_dump` to investigate where the wrong value comes from.